# jQuery :nth-child()

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a list

```
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
<article class="post">Bla bla bla</article>
```

I'd select the 5th & 6th elements, the 8th & 9th, 11th & 12th, 14th & 15th, etc etc...with

```
$('div#elencoNonHome > article.post:nth-child(???)').css('margin-left', '20px');
```

Can I do this with a jQuery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with nth-child. Just add the two statements together.

```
$('div#elencoNonHome > article.post:nth-child(3n+6)')
 .add('div#elencoNonHome > article.post:nth-child(3n+5)')
 .css('margin-left', '20px');
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W8N3A/).

Comment: And if I'd apply this to new elements? With "live"?

Comment: @Swim89 Use `.on()`. `.live()` is deprecated. Just reapply the statements again after the new elements are loaded.

Comment: Can you write me an example please?

Comment: @Swim89 I can't just write you an example without knowing what you're trying to do. Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and explain it.

Comment: This is my example http://jsfiddle.net/wpLFx/1/
I'd put the same effect at new "article" tags created...

Comment: @Swim89 Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can modify the HTML after it is loaded. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wpLFx/2/). I replaced the AJAX call with pre-defined HTML just to illustrate what you can do to modify it. I first place it in a temporary div, then modify it and place it into the main div.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with nth-child. It's got fairly simplistic row-matching logic. But if you reverse the logic, so that the default margin is `20px`, then use nth-child to pull rows #7, #10, #13, etc... to whatever it should be otherwise

e.g.

```
$('div#elencoNonHome > article.post').css('margin-left', '20px');
$('div#elencoNonHome > article.post:nth-child("3n+7")').css('margin-left', 0)
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do what the OP wants (even after fixing the extra double quotes that cause an error message). http://jsfiddle.net/R4vX2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not.

```
$('div#elencoNonHome > article.post').filter( function() {
    var index = $( this ).index();
    return index >= 4 && index % 3;
}).css('margin-left', '20px');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R4vX2/1/